# How would you translate "disinformation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on [this terminology](https://pontoon.mozilla.org/eo/terminology/) and I would like to translate the noun [`disinformation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation).

> Disinformation is false or misleading information that is spread deliberately to deceive. This is a subset of misinformation.

Please note that this is different from [`misinformation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misinformation) (that could be translated as `misinformo`) because in `disinformation` there is an intention to deceive.

> Misinformation is false or inaccurate information that is communicated regardless of an intention to deceive.

Mi uzus `malica misinformo` sed eble estas io pli konciza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Venis al mia kapo **trompinform(ad)o**. Poste mi serĉis ĉu ĝi estas uzata de iu, sed trovis nur tri trafojn en unu sama [vikipedia artikolo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong):

> Ekde la komenco de la 1980-aj jaroj, Armstrong estis la celo de
> trompinformo ke li estis konvertinĝinta al Islamo [...]

> Aliaj similaj trompinformaj historioj estis vidataj en Egiptio kaj
> Malajzio.

> Tamen, la trompinformo ne estis komplete silentigita

PS: Mi ankaŭ trovis ***falsinformado*** en Tekstaro:

> Ĉu blindigo aŭ falsinformado?

Answer (score 0):

*mensogo* [laŭ ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/mensog.html#mensog.0o&) estas

> Intence dirita malveraĵo por trompi iun

kaj [laŭ PIV](https://vortaro.net/#mensogo_kd)

> Ago, vortoj de tiu, kiu mensogas

kaj *mensogi*

> Diri tion, pri kio oni scias, ke ĝi estas malvera, aŭ nei tion, pri kio oni scias, ke ĝi estas vera

Sed ne ĉiu mensogo estas dirata malice. Eble oni mensogas al iun pro bona intenco, ekz. por ne ofendi rin aŭ por preventi disvastigi danĝeran scion.

Se vi volas emfazi malbonan intencon, eble *fi-* estus pli elegante ol *malica*. Sed *fi-* kio? **fiinformo*, **fimisinformo* aŭ **fimensogo* ŝajnas al mi ege strangaj kaj sence ne tute klaraj.

Kaj eĉ se "disinformation" ĉiam celas trompi, tia trompado ne necese estas fia aŭ malica. Do kiel "disinformation" malsamas al "lie" (*mensono*)? Al mi ŝajnas, ke "disinformation" estas iel pli vasta ol nura *mensono*. *Mensono* estas unu intence malvera diraĵo, sed "disinformation" eble *tuta sistemo* de intence malveraj, neveraj aŭ tromp-povaj diraĵoj.

Do eble ****trompaĵaro***?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, misinformation is outright false information, e.g. "Antonio Salieri poisoned Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart". In contrast disinformation usually contains a piece of truth thus making it more credible or plausible. The idea is to make the other part to act in a wrong manner. For instance the deception campaign [Operation Bodyguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Bodyguard) by the Allies during the wwii produced disinformation (the information that Allies are about to land onto the continent was true, but that British Fourth Army would land onto Norway was completely false) that misguided the Axis.

Because of that aspect of "to mislead the other" I came to think a translation of "to be misled, be led astray".  There is a verb *devojiĝi* with the following  definition and examples from [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#devoji%C4%9Di_kd). Note the figurative use.

> Deflankiĝi de la ĝusta vojo: *alvenante en la ĉirkaŭurbon, ili devojiĝis k hazarde veturadis; (f) ĉiuj devojiĝis, ĉiuj malvirtiĝis*

Turning this to a transitive verb is easy, *devojigi*, and the noun disinformation is logically *devojiga informo*.

Unfortunately Tekstaro has 80 hits for *devojig*, but the earliest are from the Old Testament by Zamenhof himself.